# How to do you ensure the page is index.php and !isset($_GET) for nav highlighting

Tags: php, nav

I am making my nav links highlighted when the page is where the link points to. However, because some of my links are simply index.php with **GET** variables, I am having trouble differentiating that with just index.php.

E.g. `index.php` and `index.php?get=**` with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` are both `/index.php`. how do I ensure that the page is at index.php without any get variables?

This is my nav highlighting code.

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/index.php'
    &&
    ! isset($_GET)
)
{ echo 'class="white"'; }
```

Comment: IIRC correctly, `$_GET` is always set.

Comment: Yes $_GET is always set in a webserver context. You need to check if it is empty like shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if $_GET is empty like this:

```
if(empty($_GET)) {
    // there are no GET paramas set this is index.php
} else {
    // there are GET params set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$_GET` is a (superglobal) array, you can check with [`count()`](http://de.php.net/count) wether elements are set or not.

```
if(count($_GET) == 0) {
  // index.php
} else {
  // get params ...
}
```